# i can not understand why a query filtering on datetime field is not working on sql server 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

This is a very basic query:

```
select * from [dbo].[TestTable]  where year(start_date)>2021
```

it returns no records, start_date is datetime, the table contains many records with that field valorized and dates beyound 2021.

this query return all the records of the table:

```
SELECT year(start_date), * FROM [dbo].[TestTable] order by start_date desc
```

[image]

this the table structure:

[image]

another query with strange result:

```
SELECT year(start_date), case when year(start_date)>2021 then 1 else 0 end, * FROM [ADS].[dbo].[TestTable] order by start_date desc
```

[image]

what can i check?

Comment: Well, neither `2020` nor `2021` are `>2021`. What exactly do you think is strange about it?

Comment: No, its not strange, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the = part of the operator. All the rows seem to have 2021-01-01, so the YEAR is not greater than 2021, it IS 2021.

You'd need to either do

```
select * from [dbo].[TestTable]  where year(start_date)>=2021
```

or

```
select * from [dbo].[TestTable]  where year(start_date)=2021
```

As Dan Guzman points out, as an additional improvement, you should avoid using functions on your WHERE clauses because that will prevent the use of indexes, since it requires to execute the function against every single row on the table to be able to determine if it's a match.

If it's a small table in terms of record count, it's not a big deal, but if you're talking about tens of thousands or more, it will add up.

The alternatives would be to either filter by the original date value, or save the year as a separate field and add an index to it.

Comment: I suggest `start_date >= '2021-01-01'` so that an index on the column can be used efficiently. Otherwise, a full scan will be required due to applying the `YEAR` function to the columns.

Answer (score 1):

It's working fine. None of the results in the picture contains record where year(start_date)>2021.

So I think you might looking for the rows where start date is greater than 2020

```
select * from [dbo].[TestTable]  where year(start_date)>2020
```

OR
select * from [dbo].[TestTable]  where year(start_date)>=2021

Or as @Dan Guzman suggested it would be better to use:

```
select * from [dbo].[TestTable]  where start_date>='2021-01-01'
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in that table has a year > 2021. There **dates** greater then the **start** of the year, but when looking at just the years, they are *equal to* 2021, not greater.

To fix this, I'd remove the `year()` function completely. Calling a function on a column can be *bad for performance*, because it impacts the ability to use indexes on the column. This one is probably not awful (`year()` is [deterministic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/deterministic-and-nondeterministic-functions?view=sql-server-ver15), and so sometimes the index is still okay), but if there is a way to express a query without the function it's usually a good idea. In this case, we can do it like this:

```
select * from [dbo].[TestTable]  where start_date >= '20210101'
```